# Google javascript (autocomplete) API doesn't work on production mode. Cities aren't coming for autocomplete

Tags: javascript

I got this message " We're sorry but the project doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue." instead of data of Cities.

How Can I enable it?

Comment: It's in your browser settings

Comment: Yes, I allowed to use Js for the site on the product. But It is still not working